# Accessing sqlite database from js/html file on users PC

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, desktop

I am trying to build a simple application for managing a database (most likely sqlite) of members of a society. The resulting app needs to be useable on windows and OSX and ideally be packaged as a single file.

My plan was to use a single HTML file that embeds all the javascript needed within the same file, which would be stored on the user's computer. The user could then simply double-click and open the page in their favourite browser, where the JS would be executed to handle the user interactions with the database and so on. On first running the sqlite database would be created on the user's machine which would persist the data and could also be backed up as needed.

My question is, how can I go about creating and modifying the database file from within the browser? Traditionally this has been a big no-no (for obvious security reasons) but looking into things like app.js and others I feel like there might be another option for achieving this simply. An option might be to have a "save/load" dialog if nothing else. The key factor is to avoid having the user install any extra dependencies like node.js etc, as this is a very simple tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can create html and js desktop applications with AIR or XUL. AIR needs the AIR runtime and will be one file to install your application and XUL needs either xulrunner or Firefox to start it. You can deliver XUL applications as a zip file and run them with `firefox --app application.ini`.

There may be more options out there

Answer (score 0):

Html5 supports both key/value and sqlite type  persistence out of the box. Depending on your needs you may be to use either or both.  They are mostly portable among most browsers now.